# Every Vulkan application crashes on RADV in swapchain creation in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: amd-graphics, 17.10, mesa, vulkan

Every Vulkan application, including LunarG SDK 1.0.61.1 demos, crash on swapchain creation in Ubuntu 17.10 (Wayland and X.org). Callstack from cube demo:

```
#0  0x00007ffff629f924 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
#1  0x00007ffff62ac695 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
#2  0x00007ffff629fceb in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
#3  0x00007ffff798c1ea in terminator_CreateSwapchainKHR () from /home/glaze/Downloads/VulkanSDK/1.0.61.1/x86_64/lib/libvulkan.so.1
#4  0x000055555555a48b in demo_prepare_buffers ()
#5  0x000055555555d51b in demo_prepare ()
#6  0x0000555555560fa0 in main ()
```

My GPU is AMD R9 Nano. **vulkaninfo** doesn't give errors and finds the validation layers and instance and device extensions:

```
Instance Extensions     count = 9
        VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
        VK_KHR_xcb_surface                  : extension revision  6
        VK_KHR_xlib_surface                 : extension revision  6
        VK_KHR_wayland_surface              : extension revision  6
        VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2: extension revision  1
        VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities : extension revision  1
        VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities: extension revision  1
        VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2    : extension revision  1
        VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  8

Device Extensions       count = 16
    VK_KHR_descriptor_update_template   : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_incremental_present          : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_maintenance1                 : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_push_descriptor              : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_sampler_mirror_clamp_to_edge : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_swapchain                    : extension revision 68
    VK_AMD_draw_indirect_count          : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_shader_draw_parameters       : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_get_memory_requirements2     : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_dedicated_allocation         : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_memory              : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_memory_fd           : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_storage_buffer_storage_class : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_variable_pointers            : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_semaphore           : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_semaphore_fd        : extension revision  1
```

Here's my environment variables:

```
export VULKAN_SDK=~/Downloads/VulkanSDK/1.0.61.1/x86_64
export PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

Are my Vulkan libraries configured wrongly or does this look like a RADV bug?

**edit (2017-11-08):** According to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-Mesa-Mir-Breaks-RADV) this could be caused by Ubuntu's Mir patches:

> If you have been trying to use the RADV Radeon Vulkan driver that's
>   packaged for Ubuntu but find it not working, chances are it's caused
>   by Canonical's patches for Mir support.

I haven't been able to try the workaround (installing drivers from a PPA: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`) but will update this question or post an answer after I do unless someone else could verify that it works.

Comment: I got a radeon 290 myself. Can't even get `vulkaninfo` to work `VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`. Got any guide of setting up RADV on Ubuntu?

Comment: @foxx1337 The only setting up I did before installing LunarG SDK was installing `mesa-vulkan-drivers` and `vulkan-utils`.

Comment: Wow, @SurvivalMachine, for my Radeon 290 the `mesa-vulkan-drivers` absolutely doesn't help with `vulkaninfo` :/

Comment: Same problem with my rx 480 on Ubuntu 17.10 with Mesa 17.2.2-0ubuntu1. The crash occurs on both X11 and Wayland.

Comment: To add to the conversation, just in case (tm) - my problem was fixed by booting the kernel with the right driver via a parameter combo - `amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0`. Radeon 290(X) is `cik`, I think 7000 series are `si`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using drivers from a PPA:

```
sudo apt purge mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils
```

According to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-Mesa-Mir-Breaks-RADV) Ubuntu's own repository's driver is broken because of their Mir patches:

> If you have been trying to use the RADV Radeon Vulkan driver that's
>   packaged for Ubuntu but find it not working, chances are it's caused
>   by Canonical's patches for Mir support.

David Airlie (RADV developer) also [blogged](https://airlied.blogspot.fi/2017/11/radv-on-ubuntu-broken-in-distro-packages.html) about this breakage.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu team also pushed an Nvidia driver update today that fixes some Vulkan related bugs. So just try to simply update to those latest drivers Ubuntu pushed might already work.